# Linq join count select

Tags: c#, .net, linq, join, count

I have this simple code that returns a list of products but now I need to somehow fetch the same lis of products BUT i need to add a new column or value based on a view count.

```
var products = db.Products.Where(p => p.ProductOwnerUserId == userID).OrderByDescending(p => p.ProductID);
```

this is what i have so far but i am no expert in LINQ so i was wondering if someone could help me here.

This is a kind of pseudo-code of what i am looking for

```
var products = from p in db.Products
               join pr in db.Reviews on p.ProductID equals pr.ReviewForProductID 
               into g select new 
               {
                    p.*,
                    ProductView = g.Count(a => a.ReviewForProductID)
               };
```

---

i have found my OWN answer since nothing came up from you guys... but thanx for the initial tips... im quite new with linq and complexe queries can be hard to understand and fit inside existing code/view

here is my solution:

Thank you for your first answer and well just too bad for the second one that NEVER came... FYI, since my product class is a partial class already a just added another new ProductView.cs partial class containg the new Property and my query (functionnal and tested) looks like this now:

```
var products = (from p in db.Products
              join pr in db.Reviews on p.ProductID equals pr.ReviewForProductID
              into g
              select new GenericEcomDataAccess.Product
              {
                  ProductID = p.ProductID,
                  ProductOwnerUserId = p.ProductOwnerUserId,
                  ProductCurrency = p.ProductCurrency,
                  ProductDescription = p.ProductDescription,
                  ProductPrice = p.ProductPrice,
                  ProductImage = p.ProductImage,
                  ProductName = p.ProductName,
                  ProductCount = g.Count()
              }).Where(p => p.ProductOwnerUserId == userID)
              .OrderByDescending(p => p.ProductID).AsEnumerable();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var products = db.Products.Where(p => p.ProductOwnerUserId == userID)
             .OrderByDescending(p => p.ProductID)
             .Select(p=> new {Product = p, Count = p.Reviews.Count()});
```

If you have the foreign keys set up properly

Comment: My next question is: M view was using this @model IEnumerable<GenericEcomDataAccess.Product> but not i am stuck with the right query but with an anonymous type!? How can i convert this anonymous type back to a product list? i tried to remove the "new" instruction but without success. someone can help with this? i just need to have a list of product but add another information "the count"